# how to work with large training set when dealing with auto-encoders on google colaboratory?

Tags: numpy, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, training-data

I am training an auto-encoder (keras) on google colab. however, I have 25000 input image and 25000 output image. I tried to:
1- copy the large file from google drive to colab each time (takes 5-6 hours).
2- convert the set to numpy array but when normalizing the images, the size get a lot bigger (from 7GB to 24GB for example) and then I can not fit it into the ram memory.
3- I can not zip and unzip my data.
So please, if anyone knows how to convert it into numpy array( and normalize it) without having large file(24GB).

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do :

1. Zip all the images and load the `.zip` file on your Google Drive
2. Dezip in your colab :

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile('data.zip', 'r') as zip:
   zip.extractall()
```

3. All your images are dezipped and stored on the Colab Disk, now you can have a faster acces to them.
4. Use Generators in keras like [`flow_from_directory`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory) or create your own generator
5. use you generator when you fit your model :

```
moel.fit(train_generator, steps_per_epoch = ntrain // batch_size,
         epochs=epochs,validation_data=val_generator, 
         validation_steps= nval // batch_size)
```

with `ntrain` and `nval` the number of images in your train and validation dataset